# Reg Exp how to match text after html element

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i have code like this:

```
<span class="someclass" style="display:none"></span> Some text
```

how to match only the "Some" word? with regExp for Javascript
10x

Comment: You have that HTML as a string, or as HTML?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? There are thousand of ways to match the "some" word here the easiest regex would be "some" but i guess thats not what you need so please explain it a bit further.

Comment: yes it comes like string. "Some" can by any word. I want to match the first word right after the end of the span element or any other element

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. It's the wrong tool for the job, especially given that you could simply add it to a document fragment and get the text directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to put "Some text" into a 'div' so you can reference it

```
var str=document.getElementById("myText").innerText; 
var patt1=/(Some)/g;
document.write(patt1.test(str));
```

That will return true

Here is a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/4df3w/1/

Change the text inside to see the difference.

---

**EDIT**: I see you didn't literally mean the word '*Some*'. Put the text in a div, and in the function do this:

```
var str = document.getElementById("myText").innerText; 
var match = str.split(" ")[0];
document.write(match);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4df3w/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var myString = '<span class="someclass" style="display:none"></span> Some text';

var regex = /<\/span> (\w+)/ig;

console.log(regex.exec(myString)[1]);
```

This will output First word after "< /span > "

Edit:

```
var regex = /<\/\w+> (\w+)/ig;
```

This will match any closing tag

Answer (score 0):

With DOM:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].nextSibling.textContent.split(' ')[0]
```

(obviously, getElementsByTagName('span')[0] may not be the most direct route to finding your node)

With regex:

```
var text = '<span ...>blahblah</span> Some text';
var rx = /<\/(.*?)> ?(\S+)/;
console.log(text.match(rx)[2]);
```

Comment: I'd probably suggest `document.querySelector(".someclass");` for this.